# How to signal the disconnecting/closing of a NSOutputStream to the endpoint of the stream?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, ios

I send up a tcp network connection via `NSNetService(Browser)`.

Later i like to close the connection and inform the endpoint of the stream about.

I properly close the streams, remove them from the runloop, set the delegate nil and dispose the stream objects, but the receiver wan't get any event.

If i force quit/stop debugging  the application then the receiver will immediately get the `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` Event.

Is there a way to send a `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` to the receiver ?

The best would be a solution that works booth iOS and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself ...

Later when i start to close the connection i suppose to get the streams to close via
[NSNetService getInputStream: OutputStream] and then i try to close these streams.
But i will get different streams, other when i open them.
So i keep a pointer to the opend streams and close this ones later. And then it works.

ploenne